# Why is it that whenever I connect to a VPN, I get a, Network Discovery Service Disabled?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I just purchased VPN service through Private Internet Access and every time I connect through them, I get this message: `Network Discovery Service Disabled.`

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Possibly a dublicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/339702/network-service-discovery-disabled-what-does-this-mean-for-me