# Network service discovery disabled and WHR-300 Buffalo firmware

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns

I had a problem recently experience by some users and perapsh solved in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339702/network-service-discovery-disabled-what-does-this-mean-for-me) . Unluckly for me, they are not working. I   followed these steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/avahi-deamon` and I change the local detection from 1 to 0 and reboot.
2. `sudo nano /etc/avahi/avahi-deamon.conf` and de-comment the line `domain-name=.alocal` as suggested [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/resolving-local-ubuntu-38861.html) and reboot.
3. making both changes and then reboot.

In all the three cases every time I try to open firefox web browser I receive this screen

[image: screen]

As done at the end of [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2120289&page=2&s=5202765e3a38c49f742e2ac5a145b2dc) I attached here all the informations I could be able to give you in order to better help me.

```
$ ifconfig | grep 'inet addr'
inet addr:192.168.11.3 Bcast:192.168.11.255 Mask:255.255.255.0    
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0

$ lost -t SOA local
local has address 192.168.11.1
```

Also, someone pointed out another file in `/etc/network/if/up.d/avahi-daemon` which I attached [here as a txt](https://ufile.io/ea89a).

### Update

The `ifconfig` returns me

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:0f:92:7c:3a  
          inet addr:212.14.9.221  Bcast:212.14.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ac26:404:38d4:e635/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:939985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:591143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:894254059 (894.2 MB)  TX bytes:75797571 (75.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:51159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:3964312 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:3964312 (3.9 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:1c:a8:22:fb:ab  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Many thanks to all.

Comment: Your router seems to be not connected to the internet. What does it have to do with `avahi`?

Comment: @CelticWarrior thanks for the fast answer. It is connected with avahi because if I do not manage to change the local config in the files I have, each time I try to connect to the router, the message `Network service discovery ...` .Maybe these two errors are not related one to another I don't know . I did a `ping -c1 www.google.com` and I receved the following: `1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% losses...` . When I tried `sudo iconfig eth0 up` I instead recieved `eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device` its possible my eth has different name (not eth0) how may I check?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Could you please post `ifconfig`?