# .local domain incompatible with Avahi network

Tags: networking, server, wireless, network-manager, wired

everyone!

Now, **I've never had this problem before**, so I ask you to please help me.
After normally turning on my PC, I get welcomed with a message

> Your current network has a .local domain, which is not recommended and incompatible with the Avahi network service discovery. The service has been disabled.

A problem has occurred at the same time with Wi-Fi and wired connection, and so I can no longer connect to the Internet.

I went browsing the forum. In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339702/network-service-discovery-disabled-what-does-this-mean-for-me) I scavenged

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/avahi-daemon
```

and changed

```
AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0
```

but the problem hasn't gone away. Could someone please help me?

Comment: What is your  computer's FQDN set to? And what is the content of your `/etc/hosts` file? It sounds like you've assigned your computer to be named `something.local`, which would cause such a problem.

Comment: Those are contents of my `/etc/hosts` file:
`127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1 peroalex-X555LAB

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`