# Is there a way for me to know why I have Avahi?

Tags: networking, avahi

For the past couple of weeks, I've been getting near-constant error notifications from Ubuntu (18.04 Cinnamon)

> Network service discovery disabled
>
> Your current network has a .local domain, which is not recommended and incompatible with the Avahi network service discovery.  The service has been disabled.

I had never heard of Avahi in my life until these showed up.  According to [this AskUbuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339702/network-service-discovery-disabled-what-does-this-mean-for-me), this is some sort of network software used for things like iTunes.  I have never used iTunes on this computer.  I haven't installed any programs that correlate to when these started to appear, as far as I can recall.  The last things I can think of that I installed are the Spotify and Discord clients for Linux, both a couple of months ago, at least.

I'm prepared to disable it as outlined in the post I linked to, but I have to assume that it's there for a reason and some program is using it.  Is there any way for me to know why Avahi is active on my system so that I don't break something by disabling it?

Comment: The easiest way is just to leave it as is. But you can disable it. It is safe.

Comment: Everyone has `avahi` installed. But not all ISP's or routers have `.local` domain.

Comment: @Pilot6 That is the post I linked to in my question.  So no, it does not answer my question.

Comment: It does answer your question. It has direction how to disable avahi warning.

Comment: @Pilot6 My question is not "How do I disable it," it's "Why did this start being a problem?  How do I determine, using Ubuntu's tools, what program was installed or updated that started generating this additional problem in my life?"

Comment: This is not a problem. Your ISP is using `.local` domain and avahi warns you about it.

Comment: You probably didn't read all answers. See https://askubuntu.com/a/616921/167850

Comment: @Pilot6 I read them, but I don't understand your comment or the answer you linked to because I don't know much about networking.  From context, it seems like you're proposing that my ISP did something?  Is that the only thing that would cause this error?

Comment: Yes, it's the only thing. You can disable this warning as described it other answer, or leave it as is.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Do whatever you want with this question